# Wordpress,how to fix pop-up when navigating to the product page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, custom-wordpress-pages

When I go to the product page a window pops up, the - **"Could not find your position. Please enter it manually."** how do I fix it?
Can this be problem of any configuration in .htaccess file?

[**website link**](http://cosmowebtest.info/shop)

Wordpress Theme - G5Plus OrsonВерсия: 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Removed the plugins that conflicted with theme products pages; WP Store locator & Redux Framework now all remarkably.